# How to pass an interface as a prop in React w/ TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'd like to pass an object into my functional component. This object has a consistent formatting so I'm using an interface. Here's the functional component parameters line:

```
interface Option { value: any, label: string; } 

export default function JSelect(options: Option[], primaryColor: string, textColor: string) {
```

and here's the usage of the component:

```
interface Option { value: any, label: string; }
const letteroptions: Option[] = [
    { value: 0, label: 'Ab' },
    { value: 1, label: 'A' },
    { value: 2, label: 'Bb' },
    { value: 3, label: 'B' },
    { value: 4, label: 'C' },
    { value: 5, label: 'Db' },
    { value: 6, label: 'D' },
    { value: 7, label: 'Eb' },
    { value: 8, label: 'E' },
    { value: 9, label: 'F' },
    { value: 10, label: 'Gb' },
    { value: 11, label: 'G' }
];

<JSelect options={letteroptions} primaryColor='#87c6bb' textColor='#2c3f43' />
```

The types are defined exactly the same, so I'm unsure why this isn't working. Here's the error I get:

> (property) options: Option[]
>
> Type '{ options: Option[]; primaryColor: string; textColor: string; }'
> is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Option[]'.   Property
> 'options' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> Option[]'.ts(2322)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export default function JSelect(options: Option[], primaryColor: string, textColor: string) {
```

If JSelect is a component, then components only receive *one* argument, not multiple. That argument is an object with the individual props. So the type for this should be:

```
interface JSelectProps {
  options: Option[],
  primaryColor: string,
  textColor: string
}

export default function JSelect(props: JSelectProps) {
  // ... do stuff with props.options, props.primaryColor, props.textColor
}
```

If you wish, you can use destructuring to break the props object up into individual variables:

```
export default function JSelect({ options, primaryColor, textColor }: JSelectProps) {
  // ... do stuff with options, primaryColor, textColor
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using multiple arguments. Your props should be fields of the first argument of your component. You should define your component as shown below instead.

```
interface JSelectProps {
  options: Option[];
  primaryColor: string;
  textColor: string;
}


export default function JSelect({
  options,
  primaryColor,
  textColor,
}: JselectProps) {}
```

If you want to learn more about typing react components. Checkout the [react typescript cheatsheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/setup)